# Specific a delimiter to separate data into columns

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, awk

I have a set of data name Book.txt and i would like to display them in shell. However im having problems trying to group my data in column with specific delimiter

Book.txt contains:

```
Harry Potter 1:Author1:100
Lord Of The Rings:Author2:200
```

Im able to display the data in Book.txt with the following code:

```
awk -F':' '{print $1 "\t" $2}' ./Book.txt
```

However i would like them to be arrange nicely in columns so i tried using pipeline column

```
awk -F':' '{print $1 "\t" $2}' ./Book.txt | column -s "/t"
```

But when i tried it, it doesnt seem to work. I couldnt use column -t as my title has whitespace and it acts as a delimiter. I would like to use 'tab' as my delimiter instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This accounts for the header and the removal of the last column:

```
$ cat file 
Book Header
Harry Potter 1:Author1:100
Lord Of The Rings:Author2:200

$ awk -F':' -v OFS=':' '{print $1, $2}' file | column -s: -t
Book Header
Harry Potter 1     Author1
Lord Of The Rings  Author2
```

Comment: hey sudo thanks it works! but could u explain abit on what this does? 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"}

Comment: You already know about `FS` which you set with `-F` this is the field separator variable which is `:` in this case, `OFS` it the output field separator which we also set to `:` so that the field seperator isn't change by `awk` allowing `column` to do it's magic using `-s:`. Please accept this answer if it was the most useful by clicking the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 5):

Can you use directly the `column` command?

`column -s ":" -t Book.txt`

Result:

```
Harry Potter 1     Author1  100
Lord Of The Rings  Author2  200
```

Comment: sorry was on cygwin.. `column` instead

Comment: Ok now its working! This piece of code is short yet does exactly what i wanted. Thanks!

Comment: @user1958567 this leaves in the 3rd column?

Comment: @sudo_O yup it also prints out the 3rd column

Comment: @user1958567 you only want the first and second column displayed correct?